# Dart Shelf server different static files on different routes

Tags: dart, dart-shelf

Is it possible to serve different static files on different routes? This is what I've tried but it does not work:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart';
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';
import 'package:shelf_static/shelf_static.dart';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  final ip = InternetAddress.anyIPv4;

  var staticHandler1 = Pipeline().addHandler(
      createStaticHandler('../one/web', defaultDocument: 'index.html'));

  var staticHandler2 = Pipeline().addHandler(
      createStaticHandler('../two/web', defaultDocument: 'index.html'));

  final router = Router()
    ..get('/one', staticHandler1)
    ..get('/two', staticHandler2);

  // For running in containers, we respect the PORT environment variable.
  final port = int.parse(Platform.environment['PORT'] ?? '8080');
  final server = await serve(router, ip, port);
  print('Server listening on port ${server.port}');
}
```

Comment: Dart is well suited for implementing Flutter. For everything else, Dart is not very well suited due to Google's lack of interest in using Dart outside of Flutter. There are at least two proofs of this. `1. Dart is a client-optimized language for fast apps on any platform`. `2. In practice, you cannot find a single serious use of Dart in server-based enterprise applications.`. On the server side, only enthusiasts use Dart. Those for whom the "bleeding edge" development model does not matter. P.S. The `shelf` implemented by Google.